Shining a Light When 2 Thermistors Deviate from Each Other
I have a heater that I am designing a control circuit for. As an additional level of safety I need to monitor 2 NTC thermistors and turn on a red led when their values differ by more than 5 degrees.
In another section I compare a thermistor to a set point with a comparator and use the comparator's output to turn on or off certain relays. Here is the circuit for reference.

I was hoping I could take this circuit as a base for my new one, but I am not sure how to proceed. My first thought is to replace "R13" with another thermistor and then find a comparator that only outputs a signal if its inputs are equal. The problem with this is that I need a signal if they are more than about 250Ω of each other.
Is there a comparator that can do this and if so how can I setup my circuit to do what I need?
Also, I cannot use any software or microcontrollers in this project. Hardware solutions only please!

Why can't you use software or microcontrollers? Is this a homework problem? If so it needs to be so tagged, and I think we need to see a bit more of your thought process in order to give hints. Also, 500Ω is a bit of a strange way to specify temperature difference in a profoundly nonlinear device such as thermistor, which makes the problem seem contrived.

Over what temperature range is this circuit expected to work? In first-order, you can detect the 5 degree differential over a very limited range. With linearization techniques, you can extended that further. For a wide range, and no software compensation, you're going to have to get fancy with a hardware-only solution.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany The reason I can't use software is a bit long winded and I don't want to get into it all, so lets just call it a design constraint and move on. No, this is not a homework problem. Since making the post I have narrowed down the exact number from 500Ω to 250Ω. I am aware that its a bit odd, but it gives about 5deg C for most of my temp range (~15-45deg C). It is not perfect, but I am accounting for that and it will work fine for my application

This will do more-or-less what you asked for. Putting the two thermistors in series compensates for the average temperature  so the window comparator responds more closely to the temperature difference.
R2- 2kΩ in this case- sets the difference in ratio, which corresponds fairly closely to temperature at about 5%/K for most NTC thermistors. R3 and R4 should be 1% tolerance or better.
It does not correspond to resistance directly. For example, using your temperature range, 15-20°C would correspond to a deviation of 285mV and 40-45°C would correspond to a deviation of 247mV. Average that at ~266mV +/-7% over the entire range for a 5°C delta.
The resistance difference is 3.2kΩ at low temperature vs. 958Ω at high temperature, so a huge difference.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you use actual RR input open-drain comparators (if such exist) rather than op-amps you can avoid the diodes by wired-or and flipping the inputs, but I'll leave that to your preferences.
